# C++ making base class conversion accessible again

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{
};

class Deriv : private Base
{
public:
    operator Base & ()
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

So I got this simple code. I'd like to make the implicit base conversion operator accessible in the deriv class. The solution above *doesn't* work because the compiler will always use the default operation (slicing) (see [C++ Define Conversion to Base Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566388)) BUT in my case I just want to make it accessible, not overloaded. Something like

```
public:
    using operator Base &();
```

it seems not possible, but I wonder why and if there are other solutions (aside of making an explicit function).

Please don't ask me why I'm doing this, I'm just looking if there's a solution to this issue I found for a very specific scenario.

Comment: If you want to make `Deriv&` to be convertible to `Base&`, why are using `private` inheritance at all?

Comment: ^ Did you truly expect us not to ask? :P

Comment: You should definitely bring some light on the nature of that *"very specific scenario"*.

Comment: In my case Base is an interface which I want to be accessible only by some specific functions taking "Base &". Regular class usage is not allowed though the Base functions. Of course I can just make a casting function, but for compatibility reasons I had thousands function calls using the implicit cast. I ended up making a class-in-the-middle where I protected all Base members with "using" and derived from it. Still, it was a strange language corner case